# Как восстановить android?

Tags: android, adb, xiaomi

Вчера поступил по глупости и удалил через adb системное приложение ("Безопасность" от xiaomi),
и смартфон начал перезагружаться постоянно.
Отладка по usb включена, root нету, fastboot отключён.
поставил новую прошивку, всё равно загружается 2 секунды поработает и опять перезагружается.
Интересует только вариант с сохранением данных.

Устройство: Redmi 9

Android: 10

Прошивка: V12.0.4.0.QJCMIXM (Global)

Comment: А какое сохранение данных интересует, если была поставлена новая прошивка? Надо при установке чистить кэш,делать вайпы